# CSS keyframe Animation not working with image

Tags: css, animation

I want to apply css animation on image only twice on mouseover

```
@keyframes vibrate
{
  0%   {transform: rotate(10deg)}
  25%  {transform: rotate(-10deg)}
  50%  {transform: rotate(0)}
  75%  {transform: rotate(10deg)}
  100% {transform: rotate(0)}
}
```

But nothing seems to work. See [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ju4cuzqL/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `-webkit-` and `-moz-` prefixes on the `@keyframes` too.

So all of the `@keyframes` will have 3 copies, 2 with the prefixes and 1 without.

Also in the `animation` shorthand definition instead of `infinite` use the number of the times you want the animation to happen, `2`.

**Demo** https://jsfiddle.net/ju4cuzqL/7/

Comment: Lack of knowledge. Good catch :-/  `+1`

Comment: Downvote without any reason is mirror image of negative thinking.

Comment: @Manwal I down-voted the answer because the demo looks identical to yours and does not address the problem. While it did point out a typo or error it wasn't relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: @Manwal That part of the change got lost in addressing the other visible issue. Demo updated.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `animation-iteration-count: 2;` if you want to control the number of iterations it runs.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ju4cuzqL/3/)

Also you have the animation explicitly running infinitely many times:

`-webkit-animation: vibrate 0.1s linear 0s infinite both;`

is the same thing as:

```
 {
    animation-name: vibrate;
    animation-duration: 0.1s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: both;
}
```

Your `infinite` property should be `2` instead:

```
animation: vibrate 0.1s linear 0s 2 both;
-webkit-animation: vibrate 0.1s linear 0s 2 both;
```

Comment: @Arbel actuall i want this animation only couple of time not `infinite` but don't have any clue.

Comment: @Manwal the edited version should clear up any confusion.

Comment: @Arbel I know... and that's precisely the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ju4cuzqL/4/ This i have reached so far its perfect as i wanted. Many cheers to @Arbel.